# Alfresco Share: accessing bpm_comment in Activiti workflow

Tags: variables, workflow, alfresco

In Activiti workflow, how can I access variable `bpm_comment` for each comment that's input by user?

If I'm using `bpm_comment` in every task, it shows the same comment (the first one).

Comment: I've found the solution for jBPM workflow [here](http://onalfresco.blogspot.com/2011/01/task-comments-in-alfresco-jbpm-workflow.html). I tried it for my problem, guessing several forms hopefully match the activiti form but no success.

Answer (score 4):

I've solved it!

In each userTask I used the following code to retrieve bpm:comment.

```
var taskId = "activiti$" + task.getId();
var taskComment = workflow.getTask(taskId).getProperties()["bpm:comment"];
```

Comment: In Alfresco 4.1, I get "ReferenceError: "task" is not defined." when I try that in an org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.script.AlfrescoScriptDelegate in a service task.