# Alfresco - Is it possible to get bpm:comment property from workflow task using Java API?

Tags: alfresco

I tried getting properties from WorkflowTask Object but not getting comment property. Currently referring to this API documentation: https://dev.alfresco.com/resource/AlfrescoOne/5.1/PublicAPI/org/alfresco/service/cmr/workflow/WorkflowTask.html

```
List<WorkflowTask> allTasks;
allTasks = workflowService.queryTasks(taskQuery,true);
for(int i=0; i<allTasks.size(); i++)
    {
        HashMap<String, Object> taskInfo = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        task = allTasks.get(i);
        Map<QName,Serializable> taskProperties =  task.getProperties();
    }
```

I ran debugging mode and checked taskProperties contents.

Comment: can you please add code on how you tried to retrieve the property?

Comment: @KrutikJayswal I have added the code

Comment: Check this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10275075/alfresco-share-accessing-bpm-comment-in-activiti-workflow?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa]

Comment: @KrutikJayswal do you have any experience using community edition of alfresco in production? if yes, what problems did you come across?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are trying to retrieve the comment of active task, tasks which are not completed yet.For those task you user needs to write comment and save it.
Once it is saved you will be able to see it.

If its not the active tasks which you are getting then,comment should not be null.
Below is output when i tried same code for retrieving the active task and printed properties.

```
{http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}created = Fri Mar 16 12:56:26 IST 2018
{http://www.alfresco.org/model/bpm/1.0}percentComplete = 0
{http://www.alfresco.org/model/bpm/1.0}pooledActors = []
{http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}name = Task
{http://www.alfresco.org/model/bpm/1.0}packageActionGroup = 
{http://www.alfresco.org/model/bpm/1.0}reassignable = true
{http://www.alfresco.org/model/bpm/1.0}outcomePropertyName = {http://www.alfresco.org/model/workflow/1.0}reviewOutcome
{http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}owner = test
{http://www.alfresco.org/model/workflow/1.0}reviewOutcome = Reject
{http://www.alfresco.org/model/bpm/1.0}taskId = 1889
{http://www.alfresco.org/model/bpm/1.0}packageItemActionGroup = edit_package_item_actions
{http://www.alfresco.org/model/bpm/1.0}dueDate = null
{http://www.alfresco.org/model/bpm/1.0}completionDate = null
{http://www.alfresco.org/model/bpm/1.0}description = asd
{http://www.alfresco.org/model/bpm/1.0}priority = 2
{http://www.alfresco.org/model/bpm/1.0}status = Not Yet Started
{http://www.alfresco.org/model/bpm/1.0}package = workspace://SpacesStore/ee203aff-9842-4d7b-b7e9-0f40b0b8a3b3
{http://www.alfresco.org/model/bpm/1.0}startDate = Fri Mar 16 12:56:26 IST 2018
{http://www.alfresco.org/model/bpm/1.0}comment = sdadasdasdasd
{http://www.alfresco.org/model/bpm/1.0}hiddenTransitions =
```

Comment: perfect answer.